# #appcelerator org.appcelerator.titanium.TiActivity 5.2.2.GA

Tags: android, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I try to run my mobile application with the 5.2.2.GA and I receive the following error:

```
org.appcelerator.titanium.TiActivity cannot be cast to
android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity; Titanium 5.2.2
```

My code is the following:

```
<activity
    android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|screenSize"
    android:name="org.appcelerator.titanium.TiActivity"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
```

How can I fix this issue? Have to change something in my code?

Comment: What are you trying to do with that code? Locking the orientation of your app? You are using the wrong activity then, there is a good guide on the [appcelerator wiki](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Orientation-section-29004932_Orientation-LimitingorientationmodesonAndroid).

Comment: The issue is with action bar tabs [link](https://camo.githubusercontent.com/252261e199057e8e17b02675f2ebd72096cac604/687474703a2f2f662e636c2e6c792f6974656d732f3164334f304a3071306a314630363172326d334c2f53637265656e25323053686f74253230323031322d31302d31322532306174253230352e30352e3032253230504d2e706e67)

this issue appears when I used the 5.2.2.GA SDK. What changes i have to do in order to fix this issue?

Comment: I tried to put that snippet of code inside of my manifest, and my app still compile and works without problems, so I don't think that it is the problem; if you remove it the application compile and works?

Comment: how can i fix this issue then? 'org.appcelerator.titanium.TiActivity cannot be cast to
android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity; Titanium 5.2.2'

Comment: Try eliminating possible causes for this issue. Remove the `<android>` section of your `tiapp.xml` for starters. Also try to think when it last worked? What changed since then?